# Task.ContinueWith Chain Sequence of Events

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

**How do I get a `ContinueWith` to wait for two tasks to complete instead of just one?**

I wanted to determine how I can chain a set of `Task`s together and have one run after the other having several levels of chaining.  I have three levels of chaining.  In the fist level I have a single task. I wanted the top level to finish before the second level starts.  In the second level I have 3 tasks.  I want 2 of the three tasks to complete before the third level starts.

---

```
TopLevel > SecondLevel A \ ThirdLevel 
           SecondLevel B /
           SecondLevel C - Don't wait for this one for the third level
```

---

I have written the following sample program to test out how this would work as follows

```
class Program
{
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    public static Random Rand { get { return rand; } }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task topLevelTask = new Task(() => DoSomeWork("topLevelTask"));
        Task secondLevelTaskA = topLevelTask.ContinueWith((task) => DoSomeWork("secondLevelTaskA"), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        Task secondLevelTaskB = topLevelTask.ContinueWith((task) => DoSomeWork("secondLevelTaskB"), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        Task secondLevelTaskC = topLevelTask.ContinueWith((task) => DoSomeWork("secondLevelTaskC"), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        Task thirdLevelTask = secondLevelTaskA.ContinueWith((task) => DoSomeWork("thirdLevelTask"), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        topLevelTask.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DoSomeWork(string task)
    {
        int sleep = Rand.Next(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Ticks {1}: Task {2}: Sleep: {3}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now, task, sleep);
        Thread.Sleep(sleep);
        Console.WriteLine("Complete Task {0}", task);
    }
}
```

For the most part this does exactly what I want.  It starts the first task and waits for it to finish, starts the 3 second level tasks in parallel.  However, I can't figure out how to set up the third level to wait for both taskA and taskB since the `ContinueWith` is set with a single parent task.

I have attempted to put `ContinueWith` for the third level task on both taskA and taskB but then it runs twice.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the output of my sample program.

[image: Program Output]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`ContinueWhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321525.aspx):

```
Task thirdLevelTask = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
    new[] { secondLevelTaskA, secondLevelTaskB },
    tasks => DoSomeWork("thirdLevelTask"),
    TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```

The advantage of this over `Task.WhenAll().ContinueWith()` is that it will work on .Net 4.0 too. And if you're on .Net 4.5, it would be probably better to use `async`-`await` instead of `ContinueWith()`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  If I replace

```
Task thirdLevelTask = secondLevelTaskA.ContinueWith((task) => DoSomeWork("thirdLevelTask"), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```

with

```
Task thirdLevelTask = Task.WhenAll(secondLevelTaskA,secondLevelTaskB).ContinueWith((task) => DoSomeWork("thirdLevelTask"), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```

It will do what I want.  Here is the new output.

[image]